# Implementing a cache layer (including some sql db tables) in couchbase

Tags: sql, couchbase, nosql

Suppose I have many SQL tables with 10 columns (at least) per each.

Let's take for example:

```
HR Table: ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Gender, City, Street, Height, Weight, IQ
```

I need to build a cache layer for all of my SQL tables.

What would be the best way to store the data in Couchbase ?

Should I store the whole document for each row ?
Here is a potential key, For example - A key that brings me a JSON document that contains all columns where its row ID=4:

```
HR_4
```

Or should I implement it like key-value store ?

For instance - A key that brings me a specific value (not the entire columns):

```
HR_4_FirstName
```

Please put in mind that I DO need to get an entire row for key in my application, but sometimes I need to get just one specific column.

The question is: Should I go for the second way, and if I need a few values - just send a few requests from my application and aggregate them ?

On the other hand, going the second way is much more keys to handle (That actually means having a key for each db field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at how your application uses and accesses the data. It may be worthwhile to have several objects for the data you are trying to store depending on access patterns and what you want to optimize for. May I recommend [this article on data modeling for a user profile store in Couchbase](http://blog.couchbase.com/user-profile-store-advanced-data-modeling). Let me know if this does not help.